# iTunes suddenly will not let me add manually album art

Tags: itunes, macos, album-art

I am running High Sierra, updated, with iTunes 12.7.2.  My Music and Album Art is on an external HD.  I rip my own music into AIFF files, then manually add the album art.  This afternoon all of a sudden it will allow me to go through the motions, but the album art does not appear in iTunes.  I have checked the permissions for some of the files and they say I have read write permissions.  Please do not suggest downgrading my music.

Comment: Weird. What happens when you right click the album in iTunes, hit Album Info, and select Artwork?

Comment: Just like before when album art. . Standard operating procedure.  When I finalize the adding the album art. nothing happens for the last three I attempted   However today I added four new CDs and album art successfully was added.  I checked the permissions on folders and artwork and the music files.  I am logged in, I'm the administrator and I have read write privileges.

Comment: Also, I went back to these three today and tried again, no success.  Open up the art work and saved with a different file name. Still no success.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it's a year late, but I had this problem which lead me here, so someone else might, too. I had been adding cds to iTunes and manually adding covers, then one day it would not save the cover image. Here's what I did:

I turned off the Airplay on my iTunes.

This worked. I could save cover art again. Also changes I made to album info (fixing the album title, etc.) reverted back. Apparently, even though it showed these edits as changed, they were not saved when my speakers were set for airplay.

Comment: This was exactly the cause in my case. I'll add that "turning off AirPlay" simply involves only checking the "Computer" box. I guess this is a permissions issue while AirPlay is active, but a warning would have been nice. Filing a bug report with Apple...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the iCloud Music Library when I manually uploaded some tracks to my library. I was able to edit all the properties, but not the artwork. When I added the artwork it never showed up in the end.

Later I have found out, how to solve this problem:

1. Remove the download of the song (you don't have to remove the song from the library, just the download via the context menu)
2. Upload the artwork again.
3. Before you save it, click on the artwork tab and select the image. It should then be bordered blue.
4. Now click save and the artwork should be saved now and also syncs to all the other devices.

I know that this question is a little bit older, but I hope to help other people with the same problem.